# PCA captures full dataset info with half of the features

Tags: pca

I have a dataset with 13 features and run PCA on it. I can see PCA with 7 principal components can explain variance 100% and reconstruction error is 0. When may this happen? I was thinking maybe these 6 useless features are just scaled version of other 7 features thus giving no information, but correlation matrix shows at most .3 score. Any idea why this may happen?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your PCA model, you started with 13 prospective variables.  And, your PCA model used only 7 of those 13 variables that it recombined in a certain number of Principal Component functions.  And, this PCA model using just 7 of the 13 prospective variables performs really well.

You observe that the correlations between the Xs are very low at = < 0.3.  This suggests that there are no multicollinearity between those Xs variables.  Given that, your complex PCA model may add no value over a more transparent OLS regression model.  I suspect that if you run such an OLS regression with the mentioned 7 selected variables, it will perform as well as the PCA model

If your 7 X variables have strong correlations with Y, and not with each other; It is very likely you will generate a model with a high R Square (explaining much of the variance of Y)regardless if it is a PCA or an OLS regression.  The fact that 6 of the 13 variables are superfluous is a very common occurrence with such models.

However, near perfect model performance usually triggers caution.  Make sure that your model is not overfit.  Your model may fit the data.  But, is it predictive?  Does it do well in hold out out-of-sample testing, testing on new data, or cross validation.

Also, are your Y and Xs variables properly transformed?  If you have time series data, you should make sure that such variables are fully detrended to render them stationary.  Otherwise, it is very easy to get what looks like perfect models that are truly meaningless and non-predictive.  Clive Granger has covered those situations with papers on spurious regressions.

Comment: .3 correlation is not with label y. It is among these 13 features. I am trying to understand how we can recover fully removing 6 features and only retaining 7 components. I don't have labels for the dataset.

Comment: I think what you stated makes sense, multicolliniarity. correlation doesn't show this.